# For a responsive view of 768px, body is {overflow: hidden;} but it doesn't work. I have two divs withing the body. They are displayed side by side

Tags: html, css

Basically I am trying to make a responsive view for a project I am working on. I am having trouble when I make the body {overflow: hidden;} and then make the class outer {right: -100%}. I am still able to scroll right and down even though body is overflow hidden.

```css
.column {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.outer {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.inner-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.inner-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .column {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .outer {
    width: 75%;
    right: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-1"></div>
  <div class="inner-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not make all your page with `position:absolute`

To make the absolute element relative to his parent, you must add `position:relative`

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)